# How to apply SELinux file_contexts change on AOSP device without a full image flash?

Tags: android-source, selinux

I am modifying SELinux policies for a hardware device running Android 9.

Currently my process is like this:

0. Run the device as userdebug but with SELinux set to enforcing
1. Make changes to `.te` files and/or `file_contexts`
2. Build the policies using `mmm system/sepolicy`
3. Push the policies on the device using the following script:

```
    adb root
    adb wait-for-device
    adb remount
    adb wait-for-device
    
    adb push out/target/product/<PRODUCT_NAME>/vendor/etc/selinux /vendor/etc/
    adb push out/target/product/<PRODUCT_NAME>/system/etc/selinux /system/etc/
    adb shell sync; sync; sync;
    
    adb reboot
```

4. Test and go back to step 1 if needed.

This process seems to work fine when modifications involve `.te` files. But when I modify the `file_contexts`, this doesn't work, and labels I changed are not applied on the device.
For now, I have to do a full make and flash when I modify `file_contexts`, which is very time consuming...

So is there a way to apply `file_contexts` changes without a full make/flash ?

Comment: Are you making changes to vendor sepolicies only? Building and flashing `vendorimage` and `vbmeta` should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, for the most part in vendor sepolicies, but not always?
So if modifying vendor policies "make vendorimage" and flashing the vendor.img and vbmeta.img ?
And "make systemimage" for system policies? That should be quiciker than a full make, thank you :)

Any way to apply them without making and flashing images, but just by pushing files somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is `product/etc/selinux` or `odm/etc/selinux` in the `${ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT}`.
If they exist, you have to push them into the device too.

The `file_contexts` is only applied if the file or directory is created via `init.rc` or after running the `restorecon` command.

If the file or directory is created by `adb shell` or any other process runtime, the selinux context will inherit its parent.